# JavaScript .map using multiple array sources

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

I have a test that provides 4 values:

`fPortTotal` = a number with how many ports in a firewall test.

`fProtocol` = an array with what protocol the port is (ex. UDP, TCP)

`fPorts` = an array with what port number

`fStatus` = an array with open or closed depending on the port

in all the arrays [0] is the first port, [1] is the 2nd, and so on.
I want to use the .map method to display each port's information in a `<p>`. The issue is I'm having a large amount of difficulty understanding the .map method and how to use it. I beleave the "skeleton" of the function should look like this:

```
function populateFw(fPorts, fStatus, fPortTotal, fProtocol) {
    var output = document.getElementById('firewallRes');
    var text = document.createElement ('p');
    text.id = 'firewallEndResults';
    text.innerHTML = arrayOfArrays.map;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i understand `arrayOfArrays.map` is useless at this point

Comment: Having separate arrays is what's making this difficult. Why not have one array of objects like `[{ fPort: 80, fProtocol: "TCP", fStatus: "Open" }, ...]`?

Comment: `.map` callback function gets an index as the second argument, so you could do something like `fPorts.map((fport, index) => doSomething(fport, fStatus[index], fPortTotal[index], fProtocol[index])` - what you do in doSomething is up to you

Comment: @phil the program that is provided to me is what is causing the separate arrays, i have no control over it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function populateFw(fPorts, fStatus, fPortTotal, fProtocol) {
    var output = document.getElementById('firewallRes');
    fPorts.forEach((port, index) => {
       const text = document.createElement('p');
       text.innerText= `${port}: ${fProtocol[index]} - ${fStatus[index]}`;
       output.appendChild(text);
    })
}
```

Comment: my inexperienced eyes tell me this is using Jquery?

Comment: no jquery...the dollars signs you see there is cause I am using template literals for the strings. look it up :)

Comment: ok, thank you, everybody. this is probably enough for me to go on.

Comment: @Talmachel Marian Silviu currently im trying to change the printed value of each fStatus value from 1/0 to open/closed and colored text. do you have a suggestion on how i can do this?

Comment: to change from true and false to 1 and 0 you can do like this, text.innerText= `${port}: ${fProtocol[index]} - ${fStatus[index]? 1 : 0}`;     -> as for the styling that should be the subject of another question.

Answer (score 2):

ForEach would be better here. Map returns an object, you don't need that.

```
fStatus.forEach((_, index)=>{
  //then using index acces all the information
  const protocol = fProtocol[index];
  const protNumber = fPorts[index]
  ....
  text.innerHTML += 'Protocol is '+protocol+' and port number is '+protNumber;
});
```

Edit: also example of Talmacel Marian Silviu is basically the same thing.

Comment: yep I was writing it at the same time :)

Comment: what is the _ refrencing? im still understanding arrays :)

Comment: the _ was used because he didn't use the status in the final solution, that could have also been named status and then you could add status in the string you are creating.

Comment: status in this case, i just used `_` because I wasn't going to use this argument in the exmaple

Comment: so its just a name i can create like a variable?

Comment: yes you could give it any name...the first name in the callback function that forEach receives will take the value of each element in the array one by one starting with the first element and looping through them until the last

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
for(i=0; i<fPorts; i++){
  var text = document.createElement ('p');
  text.id = `firewallEndResults${i}`;
  text.innerHTML = `${fStatus[i]}, ${fPortTotal[i]}, ${fProtocol[i]}`;
  somediv.appendChild(text); // don't forget  
}
```

map is function for change array items and need callback

```
const newArray = arrayOfArrays.map(callback)
```

or

const newArray = arrayOfArrays.map((i)=>{ do something in cycle })

if you use React you can use map in JSX, but this is other story

Comment: dont you mean i<fPorts.length?